# How to force keyboard with symbols in mobile website in Android

Tags: android, html, android-softkeyboard

I have a mobile website and it has some HTML input elements in it, like this:

`<input type="number"/>`

I have made the site viewable by an Android application.

Is it possible to get the keyboard with symbols instead of the default one with letters when this HTML input element is focused?

It works with IOs using `type="number"` but on android it shows just a number pad.

[image: ios vs android]

Comment: There are over 8,000 Android device models. These will ship with many, many different input methods (a.k.a., soft keyboards), and others can be downloaded by users from the Play Store and elsewhere. There is no requirement for any input method to have a "keyboard with symbols instead of... one with letters". There is no way for native Android apps to request a "keyboard with symbols instead of... one with letters", let alone for Web sites to request that.

Comment: @CommonsWare. I guess I need to clarify. I want the default symbols keyboard show up similar to how it is shown in IOS. I don't want a custom.

Answer (score 1):

The only input you can control reliably is your own. If you want to ensure that there is a keyboard with the right symbols you can:

- Specify no inputType (the default keyboard usually has all supported characters)
- Create an in-website keyboard.

I dealt with the same problem in the past. We finally settled on the first solution in combination with custom input validation. But none of them are actually good.